Flutter project in VS Code - java bin unable to run
I'm learning flutter, and went to continue after a few weeks since I last touched the project.  Out of habit I installed the updated on Ubuntu (24.04) and now for some reason the java bin can't run.
Also when I tried running without debugging, the JAVA_HOME isn't being read.
Also for some reason, the flutter doctor -v command is not thorough, as I do have Android Studio installed, as well as Chrome.
Note: When trying to debug on the Host machine (Linux) device, it at least tried to start a window and got that far.  To me that almost means the Android device emulator isn't accessing the JAVA_HOME path.
[user]@workstation:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64

~/Projects/namer_app$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on Freedesktop SDK 23.08 (Flatpak runtime) 6.8.0-41-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.22.3 on channel stable at /home/[user]/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0850beeb2 (7 weeks ago), 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
    • Engine revision 235db911ba
    • Dart version 3.4.4
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/[user]/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/[user]/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    ✗ Cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to determine the version

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Freedesktop SDK 23.08 (Flatpak runtime) 6.8.0-41-generic

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

